# extractValue and right outer join - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, outer-join

i got a little (at least i hope so) problem with an SQL Query. Here's my join

```
WHERE obj.mod_type = 'SER'
   and obj.wrk_id=wrk_lang.id(+)
   and extractvalue(value(shm),'/*/@xmi:id','xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"') = extractvalue(value(shm_con),'/*/@source')(+)
```

It gives me an "ORA-00936: missing expression"

When i remove the second outer join it works fine(also with a regular join).

Can smb. help me?

Comment: probably you should write `value(shm_con(+))`. But using ANSI JOIN would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like this is actually a LEFT outer join - in old-style Oracle syntax the (+) is put on the *optional* side of the join while in ANSI syntax the *required* side (LEFT or RIGHT) is called out in the JOIN specification - see [this AskTom reference](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:6585774577187) for examples.  So, expanding on @FlorinGhita's recommendation to use ANSI JOIN syntax (and making a bit of an assumption about the rest of the statement) we'd get something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM OBJ
  LEFT OUTER JOIN WRK_LANG
    ON (obj.wrk_id = wrk_lang.id and
        extractvalue(value(obj.shm),'/*/@xmi:id','xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI"') = 
          extractvalue(value(wrk_lang.shm_con),'/*/@source')
  WHERE obj.mod_type = 'SER';
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thx for your help! I solved the Problem with Nested Sets und an ANSI Join.